# Feasibility of solving large data problem using probability density function

Tags: probability, data-visualization

[image]We are trying to solve a problem and right now it boils down to a complex data analysis problem. Let's assume that x is a random variable and we know the probability density function for that (W(x)). Now we are going to perform the experiment for 10^(6) times. But the problem is, for each experiment instrument can't give us the exact x value. Rather it will give us roughly 10^(2) x values and say that the actual x value will be one of those. So, 10^(6) trails will give us 10^(6) data sets and each data set will contain roughly 10^(2) x values in which only one value is true value. Now in straight forward way we can choose a random combination (where one x value from each data set will be chosen randomly) and after plotting the histogram we can calculate statistical error for that and we can say for sure that the exact true combinations will minimize statistical error. But I can't check all the combinations. Because total number of combinations that I have to check is, (10^(2))^(10^(6)). Is there any smart algorithmic way to approach this problem?

Thank you in advance.

Let's assume that the red circled x values are the right combination which actually occur in our experiment. We want to find that exact right combination. But as you can see that the total number of combinations that I have to check is huge and checking all combinations will take infinite time. Hence my question is, Is there any other way to approach this problem?

Comment: I don't think you have formulated your problem yet.  Could you please explain what your experiment is attempting to achieve?

Comment: Are the possible points in some intervals or following some other nice rule or are they some (seemingly) random and unconnected subset of points?

Comment: Possible points in a particular set is totally independent of each other. They don't belong to any interval but all values are positive for sure.